# How to calculate the cost of calculations in CPU vs. cost of sending the data to GPU+performing calculations+getting data back?

Tags: algorithm, cuda, opencl, nvidia, gpu

How to calculate the cost of calculations in CPU vs. cost of sending the data to GPU+performing calculations+getting data back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a quantitative, objective way to do this other than **profiling each technique** and determining for yourself which is faster - I assume time/speed is what you mean by "cost."